# How to enable Safety Mode in YouTube via URL or Cookie

Tags: youtube, google-safesearch

Is it possible to enable Safety Mode in YouTube via a URL parameter? If so, how is this accomplished?

I am interested in doing this for an iOS app, as well as for a router rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YouTube Safety Mode is only managed through cookies rather than URL parameters. This is likely a decision made to stop people inadvertently having Safety Mode enabled by clicking on a random YouTube link.

To force Safety Mode, proxies can directly manipulate the cookie headers of outgoing requests, for example on [this Bluecoat](https://kb.bluecoat.com/index?page=content&id=KB3333&actp=RSS) article you can see the script appending `&f2=8000000` to the `PREF` cookie. If your router setup is sufficiently advanced this may be possible. The [YouTube](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174084) help article notes "Safety Mode for YouTube Mobile is not available at this time", so success on iOS depends on your implementation.

Comment: Not ideal, but with a Linux based router should be doable. Cookies are easily manipulated in iOS as well so this should work.